# Starting and stopping CountDownTimer in visibility recylcerview items

Tags: android, countdowntimer

In my `recyclerView` adapter i implemented simple CountDownTimer for 15 second, in this implementation countDownTimer work fine, in list of `recylcerview` i have some countDownTimer in layout view and i want to start and stop this countDownTimer when current row which has countDownTimer start again and when countDownTimer is not visible or its not show in list, that must be stop. like with Instagram play and stop videos

simplified adapter:

```
public class InstagramFeedsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InstagramFeedsAdapter.InstagramFeedsViewHolder> {
    ...

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final InstagramFeedsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(position);
}


public class InstagramFeedsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ...
    private boolean expanded;
    private CountDownTimer timer;

    public InstagramFeedsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }

    public void bind(int position) {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }

        timer = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
            @Override
            public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
                pager_count_down_timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;
                pager_count_down_timer.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                pager_count_down_timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                timer = null;
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

now how can i start and stop this countDownTimer on visibility items?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that any time a `ViewHolder` is bound and then unbound from `RecyclerView` the `CountDownTimer` will start again from scratch unless the `ViewHolder` is not recycling in which case their is very little point using a `RecyclerView`.

What you should do is remove the association of `Timer` from `ViewHolder` and attach it to the adapter list. That way you can keep track of how much the timer has passed by in each item individually.

You can use **`onViewAttachedToWindow(VH holder)`** and **`onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH holder)`** in `RecyclerView.Adapter` to start or stop/pause the `Timer` and you can then use **`getAdapterPosition()`** to update the adapter list.

Answer (score 0):

```
instagram_feeds.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            int firstVisibleItem = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastPos == firstVisibleItem) {
                return; //to prevent timer to restart if row position not changed
            }

            lastPos = firstVisibleItem;
            if (mCounter != null) {
                mCounter.cancel();

            }

                final InstagramFeedsAdapter.InstagramFeedsViewHolder vh = (InstagramFeedsAdapter.InstagramFeedsViewHolder) instagram_feeds
                        .findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(firstVisibleItem);
                mCounter = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
                    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
                        vh.pager_count_down_timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;
                        vh.pager_count_down_timer.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        vh.pager_count_down_timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCounter = null;
                    }
                }.start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately your coude doesn't work and `else` too, i have countDownTimer in first row and scrolling down and top couldn't change my view as `pager_count_down_timer`. in first row countDownTimer must be work

Comment: remove the the timer code from the bind method in the adapter

Comment: adapter:http://paste.debian.net/1058894/   fragment:http://paste.debian.net/1058895/

Comment: and this is my code it works with me   
adpater http://paste.debian.net/1058901/  activity:http://paste.debian.net/1058903/

Comment: could you send your full project for me?